# Identifing specific plants out indexmaps (pixelgroups) and convert to .shp

Tags: qgis, geolocation, agriculture

I am working on a project where I have to identify a specific plant (it is toxic) in fields. I made a high resolution Orthomosaic (1,4cm7/px) and created a vegetation index where the plant I am looking for is isolated and marked red. So I got a geotiff file with red pixels (single or bigger pixelgroups).

Now I'm looking for a system to can convert all these pixel to a `.shp` file. I want to export every red pixel (or pixelgroup) as a geodata in QGIS.

[image: The red pixel are the plants i am looking for]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Did you try the QGIS tool "Raster pixels to points" or "Raster pixels to polygons"?